# Why so many kinds of import/export on Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm a newbie on server side javascript, I've used nodejs before for simple things, but only the default libraries (where I never ever need to use `require` or `import` keywords), but lately I'm learning [ReactNative](http://reactnative.com)/[ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/) I've seen:

```
import RX = require('reactxp');
const popsicle = require('popsicle');
import LoginPage = require("./LoginPage");
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import AppState from './AppState';
```

And exports:

```
export default Resources; // Resources is an object
export = LoginPage; // LoginPage is a class
```

The question is, what's the difference between combination of `const-require`, `import-require` and `import-from`? also what is `export=` it seems not on the [Mozilla's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)?

Comment: *export* is described in the Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export.

Comment: @Robert `export =` is a TypeScript notation.

Comment: @Robert Node.js uses `module.exports` or `exports`. ES6 modules uses `export expression` (or similar). But `export =` (note that it is not `exports =`) is a TypeScript notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not basically differences : -

1. `const` is new in ES5. Before you had to create it explicitly or by using iffy.
2. `import` is new in ES6, which is just a replacement of `require` (which depended on common js module).
3. `Export` is also a feature of ES6, which lets you to use the `module` or `object/var` in other file.

So, It is just the new convention & nothing. And now by default in Javascript after ES6.

Also, `{}` lets you directly expose the modules/object properties, It's also new feature in ES6. E.g : -

Let's you have an object & in file obj.js:

```
 export let objj1 = {
    a : function () {},
    b : function () {},
 }
```

So Basically there are two ways to use that 
1.

> let obj = require('obj');

`a = obj.a or b = obj.b;`

OR

> import {a, b} from 'obj'

So now you can direct acess the a & b properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
import RX = require('reactxp');
import LoginPage = require("./LoginPage");
export = LoginPage; // LoginPage is a class
```

These 3 are [typescript modules import/export syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

```
const popsicle = require('popsicle');
```

This is the [nodejs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) `require`.

The rest

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import AppState from './AppState';
export default Resources; // Resources is an object
```

are [ES2015 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) ([`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)).

It's not that you can compare them: they are just import/export for different environments.